# Configuring PHP 5.3.8 on Windows 7 with IIS 7.5: strange error message

Tags: php, iis-7.5

I tried to install PHP 5.3.8 on Windows 7 with IIS 7.5.
When I browse to a PHP file, regardless of its content (e.g. empty, a simple print, a call to `phpinfo()`) I always get this message:

```
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '-' (include_path='.;c:\php\ext') in Unknown on line 0
PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '-' (include_path='.;c:\php\ext') in Unknown on line 0
```

My PHP scripts don't use any includes. I tried to setup PHP manually in IIS as FastCGI, then I also tried to uninstall PHP and reinstall it, asking to install as FastGI in IIS with the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It means PHP could not scan the directory - or C:\php\ext doesn't exist.

You can rem that line out completely in your php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was related to PHP that was mapped in IIS both as CgiModule and as FastCgiModule. I removed the CGI entry and the error disappeared.